# Creating a configuration.yml file

Tags: java, file, yaml, edit

I am working on a project and I would like to know how to store data in a file, preferably a YAML  file.

I have created a Swing GUI  for creating an account, which contains a Username  `JTextPane` and a Password  `JPasswordField`, a Create `JButton`,  and an Output.

I want it to work so that when I press the button, an `ActionListener`  is called which will write the username and password to an `accounts.yml` file, which would look like this:

```
usernames:
  leviathan: "password"
```

Don't worry about encryption,  I will take care of that later. All I ask for is how to implement this YAML file and write to it in the code.

Answer (score 1):

Java does not have pre-defined functions for writing yml files. You'd have to do one of the following:

**Use a Library**

Check out [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/450399/which-java-yaml-library-should-i-use) to see if some of these libraries would work for you.

**Writing Manually**

Creating a YAML file would be the same as creating any other type of file. For an example, see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2885173/java-how-to-create-and-write-to-a-file). You just want to set the output as `*.yml` instead of `*.txt` and when you write each line you would want to make sure to write it in the correct format.